# Load images from facebook that contain a certain tag to my website

Tags: facebook, web-services

Does anyone know how to load images from facebook that contain a certain tag?

In other words what I want to do is basically show any image where my facebook-page was taged to and show it in my website. Is this even possible?

Any idea how can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: It could be possible if [Search API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api#search) supported `#tags`, so it's  not possible for now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible by querying the `photo_tag` FQL table (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/photo_tag/) for tags of your Page, and then using the result as a subquery while querying the `photo` FQL table (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/photo/) like this:

```
select object_id, pid, src_small from photo where object_id in (select object_id from photo_tag where subject="{page_id}")
```

You have to replace `{page_id}` with the ID of your respective Page.